# Facing error in sending message from website using PHPmailer

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to fix the error but I can't. There are lot of stuff about PHPmailer on internet I tried it but my website is not sending messages. Please fix the error. I am pasting my code. Please let me know other methods to send message also.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="boxed-grey">
            <form id="contact-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <form action="ContactFormHandler.php"
                                  method="post">
                                <label for="name">
                                    Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                       id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                Email Address</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><span
                                         class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="email"
                                       class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"
                                       required="required" /></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message"
                                      class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                                      placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    require("path of phpmailer folder
                    \class.phpmailer.php");

                    $mail = new PHPMailer();

                    $mail->IsSMTP();
                    $mail->Host = "mymail.domain.com";
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                    $mail->Username = "myemail";
                    $mail->Password = "psswrd";

                    $mail->From = "you@domain.com";
                    $mail->FromName = "Your Name";
                    $mail->AddReplyTo("you@domain.com");
                    $mail->AddAddress("user@domain.com");
                    $mail->IsHTML(true);
                    $mail->Subject = "Test message sent using the
                    PHPMailer component";
                    $mail->Body = "This is a test message.";
                    $mail->Send();
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skin
pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                            Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Kindly also post yur error

Comment: it's not showing me path of php. Nothing happens when I submit message, website again loads and message shows me on url

Comment: U r missing name attribute for name and email fields

Comment: I think only email and password. other than that please let me know

Comment: Where is password field.. Plz add name attribute and chk. But I don't know where r u using email,name,message??? In php

Comment: What message r u getting in url

Comment: Is it the same file or other file `ContactFormHandler.php`

Comment: $mail->Username = "sahil.katia7@gmail.com";
     $mail->Password = "my passowrd";

Comment: in url it shows what i type in message. for example : -   http://carlmckever.com/?message=mesaaage+for+giving+example

Comment: URL said that add name attribute for name and email fields

Comment: Means. I am sorry didn't get you!

Comment: i said, add `name="name"` in name input and `name="email"` in email input

Answer (score 1):

your name and email inputs do not have a name attribute listed for them so will not send any data in the form submission.

you need to alter them as follows:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />


<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"  id="email"  placeholder="Enter email" required="required" />
```

This may not be the issue that causing the error but it will cause an issue.

Comment: do I need to make changings for email in this coding?

Comment: you will need to look in "ContactFormHandler.php" and see what values are expected and then match that to the inputs in the form on this page.

Comment: Values are matching with that.

Comment: I can give you my codes. I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

also it does not seem that you are opening php before your require statement. therefore the php section won't work.

You need this

```
<?php
require....
```

Comment: Thanks! I corrected it. But still giving me same issues